# Button event handler not fired and the text box value not stored when navigating to another pages

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am just learning ASP.net. Well, I have a little problem with asp.net web page. I have 2 web forms, WebForm1 with just a single DataGrid control, and WebForm2 with a pair of `Label` and `TextBox`, and 2 Buttons.

Straight to the point, here is my code for WebForm1:

```
Imports System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim strConn As String = ConnectionStrings("ConnStr").ConnectionString
        Dim sqlConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(strConn)
        Dim sqlComd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
        Dim sqlRead As SqlDataReader = Nothing
        Dim sqlParm As SqlParameter

        sqlParm = New SqlParameter("@Criteria", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)
        sqlParm.Value = ""

        sqlComd.Connection = sqlConn
        sqlComd.CommandText = "ShowCategory"
        sqlComd.Parameters.Add(sqlParm)
        sqlComd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        Try
            sqlConn.Open()
            sqlRead = sqlComd.ExecuteReader()
            grdCategory.DataSource = sqlRead
            grdCategory.DataBind()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        Finally
            sqlConn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub grdCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles grdCategory.SelectedIndexChanged
        Server.Transfer("~/WebForm2.aspx", False)
    End Sub
End Class
```

And here is my code for WebForm2:

```
Imports System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class WebForm2
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            Dim prevPage As Page = Me.Page.PreviousPage
            If prevPage IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim ctn As ContentPlaceHolder = CType(prevPage.Master.FindControl("MainContent"), ContentPlaceHolder)
                Dim grd As GridView = CType(ctn.FindControl("grdCategory"), GridView)
                ViewState("ID") = grd.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text
                txtName.Text = grd.SelectedRow.Cells(2).Text
                txtDesc.Text = grd.SelectedRow.Cells(3).Text
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnBack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBack.Click
        Response.Redirect("~/WebForm1.aspx")
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        Dim strConn As String = ConnectionStrings("ConnStr").ConnectionString
        Dim sqlConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(strConn)
        Dim sqlComd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
        Dim sqlParm(2) As SqlParameter

        sqlParm(0) = New SqlParameter("@CategoryID", SqlDbType.Int, 0)
        sqlParm(1) = New SqlParameter("@CategoryName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15)
        sqlParm(2) = New SqlParameter("@Description", SqlDbType.NText)

        sqlParm(0).Value = ViewState("ID").ToString
        sqlParm(1).Value = txtName.Text.Trim
        sqlParm(2).Value = txtDesc.Text.Trim

        sqlComd.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParm)
        sqlComd.CommandText = "InsertCategory"
        sqlComd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        Try
            sqlConn.Open()
            sqlComd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        Finally
            sqlConn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

The logic is, I select a row in `datagrid` control and pass the values of the selected row to the textbox control in `WebForm2`.

But after I change the value of the textbox and I press save button, the btnSave_Click did not executed and it seem the value of the textbox did not change too. I try debugging, and after I press the save button, it execute the page_load event and did not execute the btnSave_Click event.

The questions, is anyone know the reason why the btnSave_Click event did not executed, and how to fix it, so the btnSave_Click can executed after I press the button.

***EDIT***

Here is the markup for each web form

Webform1

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="grdCategory" runat="server" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Content>
```

Webform2

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm2" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <p>Category Name: </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" Width="300px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <p>Description: </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesc" Width="300px" runat="server" TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <asp:Button ID="btnBack" runat="server" Text="Back" Width="70px" OnClick="btnBack_Click" />
            &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnSave" Width="70px" Text="Save" runat="server" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Can you post your markup?  Is the OnClick="btnSave_Click" attribute there correctly?

Comment: There you are sir, the markup code for each web form.Hope you can help me sir. Thank you before.

Comment: I think the massive unabridged code dump just made this worse not better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your grd_selectedIndex change call, you need to grab the data from the cells and place it in something that can pass between pages, I would recommend session variables, but you could use viewstate or even query strings depending on what you need it to do.

on a separate note, I would not develop this using 2 separate pages, just put the stuff from the second page, into a panel on the first page, then you don't have to pull from the grid put it in another container and go back and forth.

Comment: Thanks for providing an alternative way to develop my application, thank you very much sir, you really help me.